# How can I allow user to choose his own house from google earth

Tags: python, image, polygon, google-earth

there is something I need help with it please .

My goal is to connect google earth by my website and then allow the user to choose his house and draw a polygon around his house.

Then I want the system to automatically take a picture of that house in a specific zoom in and save it into the database.

Is it possible to do in in python language and how can I do it please

Comment: it looks a bit too broad for a SO question. Can you split this into several simpler problems? It is also helpful to show what you've tried already

Comment: I totally agree with Marat. I cant just ask "I want to build a spaceship that takes me to the moon, how will I do it?" But the answer I do have is that it is very possible.